# Geometrical meaning of Atiyah-Bredon exact sequence in equivariant cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

Let a torus $T=(\mathbb C^*)^n$ act on a topological space $X$, and denote by $X_i$ the union of orbits of dimension $i$ and smaller. Suppose that the equivariant cohomology $H^*_T(X)$ are a free module over $H^*_T(pt)=S^* \chi(T)=\mathbb Q[t_1, \ldots, t_n]$. Then there is an Atiyah-Bredon exact sequence
$$0 \to H^*_T(X) \to H^*_T(X_0) \xrightarrow{d} H^{*+1}_T(X_1, X_0) \xrightarrow{d} H^{*+2}_T(X_2, X_1) \xrightarrow{d} \ldots$$
where the maps $d$ are the differentials in the exact sequence of triples $(X_{i+1}, X_i, X_{i-1})$.

**Geometrical meaning of the left inclusion**: the cohomology of an orbit,
$$H^*_T(T/K)=H^*_K(pt)=S^* \chi(K)=S^* \chi(T)/\{ \text{ characters of T, vanishing on K} \},$$
are a quotient of $H^*_T(pt)$, and the cohomology of non-trivial orbits are torsion modules. Therefore it seems natural that $H^*_T(X)$ and $H^*_T(X_0)$ "differ by torsion", that is the kernel and cokernel are torsion modules. But if $H^*_T(X)$ is a free module, then the kernel is zero.

My question is whether **there is an anologous meaning for higher steps?**